# error: assignment to expression with array type

Tags: c, array, matriz

**Estou tendo um problema onde atribui valores para a matriz e para o vetor porém mesmo assim tenho o erro de atribuição. Sou novo no forum e ainda não sei como as coisas funcionam direito, caso falte informação ou algo foi feito de maneira errada eu corrijo; agradeço desde já.**

```
const int OsEmpresarios = 4;
const int GanhosMensais = 4;

float SalariosEmpresarios [4][4] = {0};
float MediaSalarios [4] = {0};

float Media = 0;
int empresario = 0, salario = 0;

printf("Digite os salários do 1° empresário:\n");

for (empresario = 0; empresario < OsEmpresarios; ++empresario){
for (salario = 0; salario < GanhosMensais; ++salario){
    scanf("%f", &SalariosEmpresarios [empresario][salario]);
    Media += SalariosEmpresarios [empresario][salario];
}
MediaSalarios = Media / 4;
Media = 0;
printf("digite os salários do %i° empresário:\n", empresario + 2);
}

for (empresario = 0; empresario < OsEmpresarios; ++empresario){
    printf("A média salarial do empresario %i° = %.2f\n", empresario + 1, MediaSalarios[empresario]);
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Analisei o sei código e percebi que MediaSalarios é um vetor, sendo assim é necessário passar a posição que você deseja atribuir ao valor da Media dos salários, sendo assim o certo seria:

```
MediaSalarios[empresario] = Media/4;
```

Comment: bacana cara, muito obrigado, era realmente isso que faltava

Comment: Poderia colocar como resposta certa? Última coisa ai, como está dentro de um for, a posição que desejar seria: empresario. Ficando: MediaSalarios[empresario] = Media/4;

Comment: eu fiz isso, foi algo que eu realmente esqueci, e só vim lembrar agora. claro posso sim, sua resposta está correta, a unica coisa, que não sei onde posso atribuir a uma resposta que ela está correta

Comment: Do lado da minha resposta tem uma opção marcar como correta clicando no símbolo verde abaixo do botão de votar.